# How to stop tests in selenium using webdriver (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am running two tests using selenium webdriver in nodejs. I want first test to stop and then run the second one. But issues is that driver.close throws exception.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

driver.get('https://www.website.com/');

var values = [{email:'correctuser@website.com',password:'correct'},{email:'wronguser@website.com',password:'wrong'}];


testCase(values[0].email,values[0].password);

// driver.close throws exception
driver.close();

testCase(values[1].email,values[1].password);

 function testCase(email,password){
  driver.wait(until.urlIs('https://www.website.com/'))
  driver.findElement(By.id('inputEmail')).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.id('inputEmail')).sendKeys(email);
  driver.findElement(By.id('inputPassword')).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.id('inputPassword')).sendKeys(password);
  driver.findElement(By.tagName('button')).click().then(()=>{
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className('alert-danger'))).then(() =>{
      console.log('Failed login case - success');
    }).catch((e)=>{
      console.log(e);
    });
    driver.wait(until.urlIs('https://www.website.com/home')).then(() => {
      console.log('Successful login case - success');
    }).catch((e)=>{
      console.log(e);
    });
  });

}
```

Error Message :

```
(node:1296) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

Expected Result should be :

```
- Successful login case - success
- Failed login case - success
```

Comment: Why don't you have two methods for that ? If fail is one test case, success should be second test case.

Comment: I want to reuse same function for insertion of keys and detecting the response.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `driver.close()`, use `driver.quit()`.

`driver.close()` will close the existing Selenium window, if there isn't a window it will error.  It's really designed to be used when opening multiple different browser windows.

`driver.quit()` is the clean up command in selenium.  It will close any existing windows and then dereference the driver object.  It will not error if there are no windows currently open.

That being said, it's not the driver close that is causing you problems, it's the fact that the second test case you run (the line `testCase(values[1].email,values[1].password);`) is assuming that you have a browser object.  You don't because you close the last window in the previous line which results in your browser object being junked.

To get rid of this error you need to call

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();
```

again before you call

```
testCase(values[1].email,values[1].password);
```

***EDIT***

So to give you a full block of code:

```
var values = [{email:'correctuser@website.com',password:'correct'},{email:'wronguser@website.com',password:'wrong'}];
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

driver.get('https://www.website.com/');        
testCase(values[0].email,values[0].password);

driver.quit();

driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

driver.get('https://www.website.com/');
testCase(values[1].email,values[1].password);
```

Comment: I have tried adding `driver.quit()` and called `driver` again but it shows the same error.

Comment: Updated the answer to give you a full block of code, see if that helps

Comment: It gives same error in the beginning and then logs : `- Failed login case - success`

Comment: Even code till `driver.close()` also throws same exception. The issue seems to be with calling of `driver.close()` and `driver.quit()`. Whenever, I call any one of them same exception is thrown.

Comment: If you call close or quit and then try and use the driver object, then yes you will see this error.  It's telling you that you are trying to use a driver object that has not been instantiated.